# Daily pipeline depending on hourly pipeline without 24 hours available

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a daily pipeline which has a non external input dataset which itself is hourly. We know that the daily pipeline will be in Pending state for a given day, unless the hourly input data set is Ready for every hour (from 00 to 23) on that day. So here is the problem -- the active window for the pipeline producing this input dataset is starting from hour 18 (6pm) and not 00. That is because of some business reasons, that the data is only going to be available from that hour. But because of this my daily pipeline is always in Pending state for that day. Setting the upstream hourly pipeline to start from 0 is not solution because those slices will fail, and the daily pipeline will again be in Pending state. How to overcome this situation so that my daily pipeline for that day doesn't remain in Pending state?

Comment: Would it be possible to change the pipeline schedule from daily to hourly, then in the downstream code, make sure it doesn't error if there is no work to do?

Comment: No, that is not possible. It has to be daily only. One workaround I came up with is explicitly setting those hanging hourly slices on the first day to Ready. So that on the first day every hour will be Ready and hence the downstream is unblocked.

Comment: ADF pipeline property schedule has an offset atteibute that lets you push the execution time to a later time. ex:(00:19:00) to push it to 7pm.